# Ecmascript: what is the result of `GetValue([])`?

Tags: javascript, specifications

As I try to understand why this `![]` exression in Javascript is `false`, I've got stuck. I understand that `[]` is considered truthy, and that `!true` is `false` but I'd like to dive deeper.

According to the [Spec](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.9) the unary NOT operator works like this:

`Let oldValue be ToBoolean(GetValue(expr)).
If oldValue is true, return false.`

Then I tried to understand `GetValue([])` and it's all blurry right now. [Spec sec-8.7.1](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1)

Does `GetValue([])` simply returns `[].valueOf()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`GetValue` called with a plain value (not a [Reference](https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7)) returns just that plain value - in your case the array. Otherwise it would evaluate the reference to an identifier (in a variable scope) or property (in an object), but that's not the case in your example.

Comment: I see. As far as I know in Javascript only an Array, Object and a Function can be of Reference type. How can an identifier be a reference to a primitive type?

Comment: @Phil No, all of those are (object) values. Have you read the linked spec section about what a Reference is?

Answer (score 0):

On that same page, see 8.7.1 for a description of how GetValue is implemented:

https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-8.7.1

(it has nothing to do with `valueOf`)

Evaluate GetValue([]), then evaluate ToBoolean on the result, per the spec.

Comment: The `valueOf` was just a wild guess. The problem is in understanding what would `GetValue([])` return? Do you understand how that works?